# Grails: Disable form input depending on the user

Tags: grails, spring-security

App Info:

- Grails Version: 3.1.8
- Groovy Version: 2.4.6
- JVM Version: 1.8.0_60
- Spring Security: spring-security-core:3.1.1

I have a Grails form and would like to make certain fields readonly depending on the type of user. I am able to use the following taglib to determine the user.

```
<sec:ifAllGranted roles='ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPERVISOR'>
...
secure stuff here
...
</sec:ifAllGranted>
```

I can use the `readonly = "readonly"` to disable the input field. When trying to combine the 2, the result is not what I'm hoping for. Below is what I have tried to do:

```
<g:textField name="assessment" id="assessment" class="form-control"
    value="${thePerson.assessment}" readonly="${<sec:ifAllGranted roles='ROLE_ADMIN'> "readonly" </sec:ifAllGranted>}"/>
```

My logic is to embed a Groovy Expression in the readonly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type='text' name="assessment" id="assessment" class="form-control" value="${thePerson.assessment}" ${sec.ifAllGranted(roles:'ROLE_ADMIN'){ 'readonly="readonly"' }} />
```